# SSO with Classic Asp

Tags: iis, asp-classic, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am in the process of trying to implement Single Sign On for our classic asp parts of our site that run on a separate server. I have already implemented the php SSO on our other server using simpleSAMLphp. I am attempting to use shibboleth right now for the classic asp / IIS side of things. I have made it as far as getting to the login page of our Identity Provider, but once I authenticate I get stuck at /SAML2/POST and a webpage saying that the ip address of my server cannot be found. I have tried implementing fixes I found in forums but still have not made any progress. I am wondering if there is another tool that I could try to implement SSO with classic asp with? I am open to any suggestions at this point.

Comment: It would be yourself to implement SSO support (as it does not come with classic ASP, which is dead for years), or you might check if any third party has implemented it before.

Answer (score 0):

Shibboleth supports IIS using "native module" package (iis7_shib.dll).
Check this https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/IIS for further information.